# Up navigation not functionning with a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My apps `Navigation Drawer`'s button must be hidden when accessing the Settings `Fragment`, and an up navigation arrow must take its place in order to go back to the previous `Fragment` displayed.

This is how I do it, in my Setting `Fragment`:

```
((TaskForgeActivity)getActivity()).setDrawerState(false);
((TaskForgeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Where `setDrawerState` is:

```
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();

    } else {
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSupportNavigateUp();
            }
        });
        toggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

and my `onOptionItemSelected` is:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // User clicks on Settings
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        settings();
        return true;        
    } else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        TaskForgeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But for some reason my `onOptionItemSelected` is not called when I click on the up nav. arrow, and it seems like nothing is happening.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following listener (Contained in `setDrawerState`) was blocking the up navigation listener:

```
toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
    });
```

I guess two listeners were overlapping and the first one was nullified.

What I ended up doing is removing the up navigation via an interface button and set it up via the back navigation button on my phone (as it should have been done from the start).